# valgrind: Why is my tiny programming allocating so much space?

Tags: c

I'm reading through chapter 4 of "Learn C the Hard Way", where we start to work with valgrind.

One thing I noticed is that my very small programs are allocating 1,024 bytes:

```
==19896== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19896==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19896==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
```

In the book, and in other people's code it shows 0 bytes allocated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int distance = 100;

  // this is also a comment
  printf("You are %d miles away.\n", distance);

  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why there needs to be 1kb of space allocated for this thing.

This bothers me and I would like to know what is going on.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Edit: 1KB, not 1MB

Comment: What's the command that you're running?

Comment: This is not 1 MB of space, it would be 1 KiB of space allocated from the heap.

Comment: It says 1024 bytes allocated which is just 1 kb

Comment: Hmmm,  An optimizing compile may just do `puts("You are 100 miles away.");`.  Compiler settings are important when assessing code.

Answer (score 7):

That's 1KB, not 1MB.. which isn't much memory these days (35 years ago, it was a lot).

As to why it's using that much: `printf` uses buffered I/O, which allocates buffers.  The exact answer really depends upon the platform since c libraries and operating systems will vary.  But if you were to write the same program using just system calls eg. `write` instead of `printf`, you'd probably see the memory usage go down.

Comment: yay, at least one guy noticed that. 35 odd years yeah.

Comment: $/1MB_2017 about   $/1kB_1982 --> "35 years ago" just about right.

Comment: little_birdie, I changed printf to write and it *did* change the allocated space to 0 bytes. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @LeeGaines Great!  But the thing to understand is that when using buffered IO, eg.. when using the library functions `fopen`, `fclose`, `fputs` as well as `printf` and `fprintf` etc, the buffers are only allocated once per open file descriptor.  So, if you are using `printf` to write to STDOUT as you are doing here.. the buffers are allocated once for STDOUT and then used for all operations to STDOUT.  It's not allocated again for the rest of the program.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` buffers I/O before it actually writes that data to standard out (as @little_birdie mentioned). Buffered I/O refers to the practice of temporarily storing I/O operation in your application (user-space) prior to transmitting it to the kernel, which can be slow. In order to minimize these so called *system calls*, your application will ask for such memory ahead of time.

It is not uncommon for certain features of the system to disable this feature entirely, or even perhaps for a historical system to not have buffered I/O at all (although I'm not familiar with any).

If you want to disabled buffering on your `stdout` here (and thus allocation "0" bytes of heap memory), you can ask for it with `setbuf` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int distance = 100;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("You are %d miles away.\n", distance);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to learn more about this, check out the excellent [Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/)